# Changing customer_id to fax in Opencart 1.5.x

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have changed table "customer_rewards" and some other stuff what connected with rewards in Opencart 1.5.x.

Now in table "customer_rewards" **customer_id** column contains **fax** of customer.

I just have changed content of **customer_id** and now it contains fax field (I'm using this for storing discount card code) but column also named as **customer_id**.

I thought I also could edit some query and simple replace customer_id to fax but it doesn't work properly :(

Then I have add some functions but the also didn't work properly, I've got in **customer_id** column null, 0, 1 but no fax field.

Tried to edit:

/admin/controller/sale/customer.php
/admin/model/sale/customer.php

Query to get fax of user (tried this after trying with getting from other model):

```
$fax = $this->db->query("SELECT fax FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
```

All code behind without my edits.

Some parts of Model:

```
...
$customer_id = $this->db->getLastId();
...
public function addReward($customer_id, $description = '', $points = '', $order_id = 0) {
        $customer_info = $this->getCustomer($customer_id);

        if ($customer_info) { 
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', points = '" . (int)$points . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($description) . "', date_added = NOW()");

            $this->language->load('mail/customer');

            if ($order_id) {
                $this->load->model('sale/order');

                $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($order_id);

                if ($order_info) {
                    $store_name = $order_info['store_name'];
                } else {
                    $store_name = $this->config->get('config_name');
                }   
            } else {
                $store_name = $this->config->get('config_name');
            }       

            $message  = sprintf($this->language->get('text_reward_received'), $points) . "\n\n";
            $message .= sprintf($this->language->get('text_reward_total'), $this->getRewardTotal($customer_id));

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
            $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
            $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
            $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
            $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');
            $mail->setTo($customer_info['email']);
            $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setSender($store_name);
            $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('text_reward_subject'), $store_name), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->send();
        }
    }

    public function deleteReward($order_id) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
    }

    public function getRewards($customer_id, $start = 0, $limit = 10) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getTotalRewards($customer_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }

    public function getRewardTotal($customer_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(points) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }       

    public function getTotalCustomerRewardsByOrderId($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }
```

Parts of Controller what connected with Rewards:

```
public function reward() {
    $this->language->load('sale/customer');

    $this->load->model('sale/customer');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'sale/customer')) { 
        $this->model_sale_customer->addReward($this->request->get['customer_id'], $this->request->post['description'], $this->request->post['points']);

        $this->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
    } else {
        $this->data['success'] = '';
    }

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && !$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'sale/customer')) {
        $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    } else {
        $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
    }   

    $this->data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');
    $this->data['text_balance'] = $this->language->get('text_balance');

    $this->data['column_date_added'] = $this->language->get('column_date_added');
    $this->data['column_description'] = $this->language->get('column_description');
    $this->data['column_points'] = $this->language->get('column_points');

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }  

    $this->data['rewards'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_sale_customer->getRewards($this->request->get['customer_id'], ($page - 1) * 10, 10);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->data['rewards'][] = array(
            'points'      => $result['points'],
            'description' => $result['description'],
            'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
        );
    }           

    $this->data['balance'] = $this->model_sale_customer->getRewardTotal($this->request->get['customer_id']);

    $reward_total = $this->model_sale_customer->getTotalRewards($this->request->get['customer_id']);

    $pagination = new Pagination();
    $pagination->total = $reward_total;
    $pagination->page = $page;
    $pagination->limit = 10; 
    $pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
    $pagination->url = $this->url->link('sale/customer/reward', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&customer_id=' . $this->request->get['customer_id'] . '&page={page}', 'SSL');

    $this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

    $this->template = 'sale/customer_reward.tpl';   

    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

**customer_rewards table structure:**

```
customer_reward_id,
customer_id,
order_id,
description,
points,
date_added
```

Maybe you have some ideas. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
OK, I have made this it seems work fine but customer_id column contains "1" and as you see I can't get fax field properly. And now main question is how can I get fax field?

```
...
public function getFax($customer_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT fax FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }

    public function addReward($customer_id, $description = '', $points = '', $order_id = 0) {
        $customer_info = $this->getCustomer($customer_id);

        $customer_fax = $this->getFax($customer_id);

        if ($customer_info) { 
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_fax . "', order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', points = '" . (int)$points . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($description) . "', date_added = NOW()");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have used **$customer_fax=$customer_info['fax'];** to get fax field.

Comment: But I still can't get Rewards.

Comment: $results = $this->model_sale_customer->getRewards($this->request->get['customer_id'], ($page - 1) * 10, 10);

Working but with get['customer_fax'] won't work.